# moment fromNow replace hours being shown by today

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I am using moment to get the time to an event and am using the `fromNow` functionality

```
moment(value).fromNow();
```

This works well, however, and it tells me `in 4 days`. The issue is that if it less than a day then it says `in 4 hours`. Instead of this I would prefer it would say `today`.

I have updated `moment.updateLocale()`, however it now says `in today`.

Does anyone know how to rectify this with `moment`?

```
    moment.updateLocale('en', {
        relativeTime: {
            future: "in %s",
            past: "%s ago",
            s:  "today",
            m:  "today",
            mm: "today",
            h:  "today",
            hh: "today",
            d:  "1 day",
            dd: "%d days",
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the docs: If you pass true, you can get the value without the suffix. 
https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/fromnow/

```
moment(value).fromNow(true);
```

Combine it with your translations